# Issue when trying to pass data between Kubeflow components using files

Tags: python, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I made two components using python functions and I am trying to pass data between them using files, but I am unable to do so. I want to calculate the sum and then send the answer to the other component using a file. Below is the partial code (The code works without the file passing). Please assist.

```
# Define your components code as standalone python functions:======================
    def add(a: float, b: float, f: comp.OutputTextFile(float)) -> NamedTuple(
        'AddOutput',
        [
            ('out', comp.OutputTextFile(float))
        ]):
        '''Calculates sum of two arguments'''
        sum = a+b

        f.write(sum)

        from collections import namedtuple

        addOutput = namedtuple(
            'AddOutput',
            ['out'])
        return addOutput(f)  # the metrics will be uploaded to the cloud


    def multiply(c:float, d:float, f: comp.InputTextFile(float) ):
        '''Calculates the product'''
        product = c * d

        print(f.read())


add_op = comp.func_to_container_op(add, output_component_file='add_component.yaml')
    product_op = comp.create_component_from_func(multiply, 
output_component_file='multiple_component.yaml')


@dsl.pipeline(
      name='Addition-pipeline',
      description='An example pipeline that performs addition calculations.'
    )
    def my_pipeline(a, b='7', c='4', d='1'):

        add_op = pl_comp_list[0]
        product_op = pl_comp_list[1]

        first_add_task = add_op(a, 4)
        second_add_task = product_op(c, d, first_add_task.outputs['out'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly simplified version of your pipeline that I tested and which works.
It doesn't matter what class type you pass to `OutputTextFile` and `InputTextFile`. It'll be read and written as `str`. So this is what you should change:

- While writing to `OutputTextFile`: cast `sum_` from `float to str`
- While reading from `InputTextFile`: cast `f.read()` value from `str to float`

```
import kfp
from kfp import dsl
from kfp import components as comp


def add(a: float, b: float, f: comp.OutputTextFile()):
    '''Calculates sum of two arguments'''
    sum_ = a + b
    f.write(str(sum_)) # cast to str
    return sum_


def multiply(c: float, d: float, f: comp.InputTextFile()):
    '''Calculates the product'''
    in_ = float(f.read()) # cast to float
    product = c * d * in_
    print(product)
    return product


add_op = comp.func_to_container_op(add,
                                   output_component_file='add_component.yaml')
product_op = comp.create_component_from_func(
    multiply, output_component_file='multiple_component.yaml')


@dsl.pipeline(
    name='Addition-pipeline',
    description='An example pipeline that performs addition calculations.')
def my_pipeline(a, b='7', c='4', d='1'):

    first_add_task = add_op(a, b)
    second_add_task = product_op(c, d, first_add_task.output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    compiled_name = __file__ + ".yaml"
    kfp.compiler.Compiler().compile(my_pipeline, compiled_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

`('out', comp.OutputTextFile(float))`

This is not really valid. The `OutputTextFile` annotation (and other similar annotations) can only be used in the function parameters. The function return value is only for outputs that you want to output as values (not as files).

Since you already have `f: comp.OutputTextFile(float)` where you can just remove the function return value altogether. Then you pass the `f` output to the downstream component: `product_op(c, d, first_add_task.outputs['f'])`.